# push transition with searchController not animating navigationBar change in size smoothly in some cases

Tags: swift, xcode, navigationbar, uisearchcontroller

I am using largeTitles and a searchController.  when I animate a push transition, the searchBar sometimes does not animate it's disappearance.  The space for the searchBar suddenly disappears after the push causing a rough transition animation.

I thought the solution was to set the `searchController.definesPresentationContext = true` but that is not working.  Wondering if there is another fix for this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change you code to `definesPresentationContext = true` on the view controller itself.